# How to define preprocessor macros with respect to device type ?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, macros

I have found many questions related to macros but nothing can help me so please help me 
My question is define macros constant with respect to device type.

Please see below code

```
#define IPAD UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
#define IS_IPHONE ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] model ] isEqualToString: @"iPhone" ] )


#if defined(IPAD)
#define SCREENWIDTH  768
#define SCREENHEIGHT 1024
#define TWIDTH 69
#define THEIGHT 69
#define BX 42
#define BY 0
#elif defined(IS_IPHONE)
#define SCREENWIDTH  320
#define SCREENHEIGHT 480
#define TWIDTH 29
#define THEIGHT 29
#define BX 16
#define BY 34
#endif
```

this code run well on ipad but in iphone return all ipad values ?

Comment: This is not the correct way of programming for iOS as it effectively hardcodes a point value for the screen sizes.  You should retrieve this value at runtime (NOT compile time) as these are likely to change regularly. On the iPhone your values are incorrect anyway as the iPhone 5 & 5s are `320 x 568`. I strongly suggest you re-think your design and perhaps use Autolayout without any hardcoded point values. iOS 8 also removes the distinction between iPad and iPhone with a single Storyboard for both and is backwards compatible with iOS 7.

Comment: @RoboticCat #define SCREENWIDTH  768
#define SCREENHEIGHT 1024                   this line is not the part of my code i just ask it for temporary basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define SCREENWIDTH  ((IS_IPAD) ? 768 : 320)
#define SCREENHEIGHT ((IS_IPAD) ? 1024 : 480)
#define TWIDTH ((IS_IPAD) ? 69 : 29)
#define THEIGHT ((IS_IPAD) ? 69 : 29)
#define BX ((IS_IPAD) ? 42 : 16)
#define BY ((IS_IPAD) ? 0 : 34)
```

This may help
The problem in your code is that you are checking if the macro (IS_IPAD) is defined or not, so whatever the value of IS_IPAD it is always defined, thats why its not going in else part, so check the value of macro. Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of how inefficient the expanded macros will be when used?

Answer (score 2):

That's because `IPAD` and `IS_IPHONE` are designed to be used at runtime, not compile time, for example:

```
if (IPAD) {
    [self doIpadSpecificThing];
} else {
    [self doIPhoneSpecificThing];
}
```

They use `#define` to make them easier to call, but that define expands to:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    [self doIpadSpecificThing];
} else {
    [self doIPhoneSpecificThing];
}
```

They are designed to be used in a Universal app which work on both iPad and iPhone but do different things depending on which platform they are running.

Therefore you cannot define `SCREENWIDTH` etc at compile time using `IPAD` and `IS_IPHONE` and as far as I am aware there is no compile-time macros available to test for targeting iPad/iPhone (see [`TargetConditionals.h`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/CarbonHeaders/CarbonHeaders-18.1/TargetConditionals.h)).

**EDIT** A comment on the accepted answer:

This answer looks pretty clever and seems to be a good way of saving some typing.  However I would like anyone considering using that answer to consider what is happening.

Given:

```
#define UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() \
   ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(userInterfaceIdiom)] ? \
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] : \
   UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

And:

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define SCREENWIDTH  ((IS_IPAD) ? 768 : 320)
#define SCREENHEIGHT ((IS_IPAD) ? 1024 : 480)
```

Then a typical use of `SCREENWIDTH` and `SCREENHEIGHT`:

```
[self setWidth:SCREENWIDTH
        height:SCREENHEIGHT];
```

Will expand to (something like):

```
[self setWidth:([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(userInterfaceIdiom)] ? \
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] : \
   UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ? 768 : 320
        height:([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(userInterfaceIdiom)] ? \
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] : \
   UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ? 1024 : 480];
```

Now I see several duplicate method calls in that call, and that cannot be a good thing, can it?

**EDIT 2** To provide something that actually answers the question, you can use the macros from the accepted answer but also reduce the number of calls to `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()`.

Therefore whenever platform-specific code needs to be used, call `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` once at the start:

```
BOOL isIpad = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;
```

and then define the macros from the accepted answer to use that `BOOL` variable:

```
#define SCREENWIDTH  (isIpad ? 768 : 320)
#define SCREENHEIGHT (isIpad ? 1024 : 480)
#define TWIDTH (isIpad ? 69 : 29)
#define THEIGHT (isIpad ? 69 : 29)
#define BX (isIpad ? 42 : 16)
#define BY (isIpad ? 0 : 34)
```

and then the example call I give expands to the much more reasonable:

```
[self setWidth:(isIpad ? 768 : 320)
        height:(isIpad ? 1024 : 480)];
```

and then there is only one call to `[[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:]` per calling-method, instead of one per called-parameter.